# Netcdf files open with nc_open but not raster stack

Tags: azure-storage, raster, netcdf

I have nested list of temporary file pathways stored in `last_dates_path` that are netcdf format. I can open the individual files using `nc_open()` but not using `raster::stack` which thinks that the files are empty or NULL.

```
> str(lapply(last_dates_path,unlist))
List of 2
 $ ST/rfe/raw/ssa/tamsat-v3.1/dekadal/rfe{year}_{month}-dk{dek}.v3.1.nc: chr [1:15] "/tmp/RtmptMnnSG/file3fac6dc3bde4" "/tmp/RtmptMnnSG/file3fac64b2c6e" "/tmp/RtmptMnnSG/file3fac262dfde9" "/tmp/RtmptMnnSG/file3fac3e6a282f" ...
 $ ST/rfe/raw/ssa/tamsat-v3.1/daily/rfe{year}_{month}_{day}.v3.1.nc    : chr [1:151] "/tmp/RtmptMnnSG/file3fac2441b13" "/tmp/RtmptMnnSG/file3fac155e8e9f" "/tmp/RtmptMnnSG/file3fac1cc3ad22" "/tmp/RtmptMnnSG/file3fac4d61be09" ...
```

The nested list is passed to a function called `st_get_crop` that uses raster stack as below:

```
st_get_crop=function(path_to_data,shape_files = NULL,date = NULL,nc_var=NULL,sf = TRUE){
  files <- path_to_data
  #loading files in a raster stack
  if(is.null(nc_var)){
    rast <-raster::stack(files[1:length(files)], bands=1)
  }else{
    rast <-raster::stack(files[1:length(files)], varname = nc_var)
    rast<-setNames(rast,format(date,"%d_%m_%Y"))
  }
...
}
```

Here is how I pass the arguments to `st_get_crop`:

````
# Takes the data and crops it according to the shapefile input
  new_data <- partial_vect(st_get_crop, shape_files = shapefiles$MLI0)(
    path_to_data = lapply(last_dates_path,unlist),
    date = unlist(lapply(last_dates, "[[", "dates"), recursive = FALSE),
    nc_var = as.list(vect_fn2(rep)(
      metadata(quote(st_source$varname)),
      lapply(lapply(last_dates, "[[", "dates"), length)
    ))
  )```

But I continue to get the following error:
````

Error in rgdal::GDALinfo(filename, silent = silent, returnRAT = RAT, returnCategoryNames = RAT) :
object 'RATlist' not found
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'stack': Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: GDAL support is provided by the sf and terra packages among others
2: In dim(x) : no bands in dataset
3: GDAL support is provided by the sf and terra packages among others